# Writing data to a Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, label

I want to populate an html label based on user information. I know how to read the data from html to c#, and how to manipulate the data. I just dont know how to return the data from c# to the html label.

```
<asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LoginUserName">Username:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="LoginUserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="LoginPassword">Password:</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="LoginPassword" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="errorMessageLable" AssociatedControlID="errorCheck" CssClass="errorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I want to be able to fill in the error message in the errorMessageLabel.

Comment: I wasnt seeing my label in intellisense. I see it there now. Not sure what I was doing wrong before.

Comment: This kind of thing sometimes happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code-behind file (the .cs file) you should access your label this way:

```
errorMessageLable.Text = "YourErrorMessageHere";
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. I'm in a WPF app.  I don't get the ".Text" attribute for my label.

Comment: @Awesome_girl I suppose this `Text` property is only available on `ASP.NET` label control. Ah ohhh I need to congratulate you: you're a girl computer engineer. AWESOME indeed. :-))

Comment: Thank you.. somehow that comment makes me really furious